# PDO PHP - Updating row not working - no error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to update some rows in the orders table.

My code runs completely fine, but when I'm checking my phpmyadmin no rows are updated. I also tried to update a different column from the same table, that didn't work either.

Can anyone help me?

(I tried to update a row in a different table and that seemed to work fine.)

PHP:

```
    <?php
    require '../app/db.php';
    require '../app/init.php';
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || !$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
        header('Location: '.ADMIN_URL);
        exit;
    }
    //Get all orders
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, invoice_id, order_id, order_completed_at, total_shipping, shipping_tax, owner_site_name, export_csv FROM orders WHERE id > 1573");
    $sth->execute();
    $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $results = json_decode(json_encode($results), 1);
    foreach ($results as $order => $value) {
        $csv = json_decode($value['export_csv'], 1);
        $total_shipping = number_format($value['total_shipping']+$value['shipping_tax'], 2, ',', '.');
        $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(explode(' ', $value['order_completed_at'])[0]));
        $shipping = $date.';-'.$value['invoice_id'].';0;"1050";"";"'.$value['owner_site_name'].' (ID: '.$value['order_id'].')";'.$total_shipping.';"DKK";100,00;"Salg";"";0;'.$date.';0,00;;"";"";0,00;0;"";0;"";"";"";"";"";0;0,00;"";"";"";"";"";0';
        $csv['separated']['shipping'] = $shipping."\n";
        $joins = explode("\n", $csv['joined']);
        foreach ($joins as $join => $value) {
            $explode = explode(';', $value);
            if (isset($explode[3])) {
                if ($explode[3] == '"1040"') {
                    $joins[$join] = $shipping;
                }
            }
        }
        $csv['joined'] = implode("\n", $joins);
        $csv = json_encode($csv);
        //Update export_csv
        $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE `orders` SET `export_csv` = :csv WHERE `id` = :id");
        $sth->bindParam(':csv', $csv);
        $sth->bindParam(':id', $value['id']);
        $res = $sth->execute();
        if (!$res) {
            echo 'Failed for order #'.$value['id'].'<br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Table structure:

```
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";

    --
    -- Database: `xxxx`
    --

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Struktur-dump for tabellen `orders`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `owner_site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `owner_site_url` text NOT NULL,
    `owner_site_name` text NOT NULL,
    `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `order_created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `order_updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `order_completed_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `currency` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `total` double NOT NULL,
    `subtotal` double NOT NULL,
    `total_tax` double NOT NULL,
    `total_shipping` double NOT NULL,
    `shipping_tax` double NOT NULL,
    `cart_tax` double NOT NULL,
    `total_discount` double NOT NULL,
    `shipping_methods` text NOT NULL,
    `payment_details` text NOT NULL,
    `billing_address` text NOT NULL,
    `shipping_address` text NOT NULL,
    `total_line_items_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `note` text NOT NULL,
    `customer_ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `view_order_url` text NOT NULL,
    `line_items` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    `shipping_lines` text NOT NULL,
    `tax_lines` text NOT NULL,
    `fee_lines` text NOT NULL,
    `coupon_lines` text NOT NULL,
    `export_csv` text NOT NULL,
    `proforma_text` text NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Begrænsninger for dumpede tabeller
    --

    --
    -- Indeks for tabel `orders`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `orders`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_order_id` (`order_id`,`owner_site_id`);

    --
    -- Brug ikke AUTO_INCREMENT for slettede tabeller
    --

    --
    -- Tilføj AUTO_INCREMENT i tabel `orders`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `orders`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

(Maybe some sort of "force-update", because I my suspect my UNIQUE keys for being the thing which make the rows not available to update)?

Comment: Any errors? Nothing in the error logs?

Comment: There's no error checking to be seen. Is `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled?

Comment: Nope - nothing. I tried to run the $sth->rowCount(), which returned 0, so the rows aren't affected.

Comment: I have error mode enabled. See images: https://gyazo.com/dab3627cba5c2b7902abb153ae2f5598

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode($results), 1)` Wait, what?

Comment: Yea, that must be a mistake, though it doesn't affect the code. (i just removed it)

Comment: Are you sure you need both single and double quotes in `if ($explode[3] == '"1040"') {`? Maybe that should just be `if ($explode[3] == '1040') {`.

Comment: +Barmar, yes that I'm fully aware of, and it is on purpose, when the string equals "1040" some parts of that lines must be replaced. That's the part I want to update.

Comment: Not the issue, but I really dislike the passing of "1" to the `json_decode`. It makes it look like an integer parameter when actually it's being interpreted as a boolean.

Comment: +Chris, It's removed therefore it doesn't matter anymore. I just want this to update, I've got a short deadline and I've been looking at this for hours now. But sure you could just put (bool) in front. Though, with it being an integer it stills works, and looks cleaner.

Comment: 36 fields all NOT NULL? In dire need of normalization.

Comment: +david, is that a problem, if not I will not bother changing it, because it is a live website, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

After further debugging i found that the `$value['id']` was NULL.

I can't explain why, but I instead used the `$results[$order]['id']` to fetch the id for the row.